# vite/rollup with @rollup/plugin-babel does not strip template literal backticks when set to ie >= 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, babeljs, template-literals, vite

Attempting to use Vite in library mode to compile an ES6 `.js` files down to a bundled ES5 `.js` file that will run in Internet Explorer 11. In my actual app there are several files that use ESM import/export, however I have verified that I can reproduce the problem with a single, simplified example file.  Which I will include below.

Here is my configuration:

```
//vite.config.js
const path = require('path');
const { defineConfig } = require('vite');
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';

module.exports = defineConfig({
  esbuild: false,
  plugins: [
    babel({
      babelHelpers: 'bundled',
      presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { browsers: 'defaults, ie >= 11' } }]],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    outDir: 'javascript',
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js-src/index.js'),
      name: 'MyLib',
      fileName: (format) => 'my-lib.js',
    },
  },
});
```

Test File:

```
const aWord = 'World';
const multiLineString = `
  Hello ${aWord}
`;
console.log(multiLineString);
```

Resulting output file:

```
(function(n){typeof define=="function"&&define.amd?define(n):n()})(function(){"use strict";var n=`
  Hello `.concat(aWord,`
`);console.log(n)});
```

Notice how the transpiled code does down-shift to ES5 (see `var` instead of `const`) but it does not remove the template literal backticks and convert them to some other type of string that is safe for Internet Explorer 11. It only happens on multi-line template literal strings though. A single-line template literal will get changed to a string with `"` characters.

Looking for a solution to force babel to remove these backtick characters and convert them a supported type of string (that preserves the linebreaks as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the culprit.
It is not Babel but Esbuild.

After Babel has done a great job on transpiling everything properly (I checked, it does) the optimization kicks in and Esbuild (by default) "optimizes" those newly arrived linebreaks "\n" back into much slimmer (char wise) multiline strings.

I see that you tried to disable Esbuild with `esbuild = false` but maybe this wasn't the correct config option "back then" (in Nov21) to stop Esbuild from messing up your results.

In order to stop Esbuild from re-transpiling strings with line breaks back  multiline strings you have two options

- disable minification: `build.minify = false`
- or set `build.target = 'ie11'`

Once `build.target` is set to `ie11` the build process will start complaining that Esbuild is not ready to transpile quite some parts of your code to IE11 specification. I assume that this is because Esbuild runs before the plugins are ran and later again for the final optimization.

So using `@vite/babel` is not an option anymore, the new Babel-way goes via `@rollup/plugin-babel`.

The following is my working `vite.config.js` or at least the important parts to it:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { getBabelOutputPlugin } from '@rollup/plugin-babel'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    target: 'ie11',
    lib: {
      /* your vite lib mode params */
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: [],
      output: {
        plugins: [
          /**
           * Running Babel on the generated code:
           *  https://github.com/rollup/plugins/blob/master/packages/babel/README.md#running-babel-on-the-generated-code
           *
           * Transforming ES6+ syntax to ES5 is not supported yet, there are two ways to do:
           *  https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1010#issuecomment-803865232
           * We choose to run Babel on the output files after esbuild.
           *
           * @vitejs/plugin-legacy does not support library mode:
           *  https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1639
           */
          getBabelOutputPlugin({
            allowAllFormats: true,
            presets: [
              [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                {
                  targets: '> 0.25%, not dead, IE 11',
                  useBuiltIns: false, // Default：false
                  // // https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules
                  modules: false
                },
              ]
            ]
          }),
        ]
      },
      plugins: [...]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@vitejs/plugin-legacy](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/plugin-legacy) to support IE 11 in Vite.

I test with a simple Vite project with vanilla JavaScript and add the test file code like yours. I first run `npm i -D @vitejs/plugin-legacy`, then use a **vite.config.js** file like below:

```
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy'

export default {
  plugins: [
    legacy({
      targets: ['ie >= 11'],
      additionalLegacyPolyfills: ['regenerator-runtime/runtime']
    })
  ]
}
```

Then I run `npm run build`, the generated js file in **dist** folder is like below which supports IE 11:

```
System.register([],(function(){"use strict";return{execute:function(){var e="\n  Hello ".concat("World","\n");console.log(e)}}}));
```

Comment: I tried that but the project I am creating needs to be in vite's "library mode" and I got an error when trying to use plugin-legacy that it does not support library mode. https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1639

Comment: I can reproduce the issue when use @rollup/plugin-babel. I haven't found the solution yet. I suggest that you can open an issue in Vite GitHub. I also find [a similar issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel/issues/259) and you can refer to it.